# is there a way to check signature/hash of the iso file and autoinstall seed file (user-data)?

Tags: boot, server

we can use following kernel parameter to automatically install ubuntu server: `kernel vmlinuz verbose debug=1 ip=dhcp boot=casper netboot=url url=<url of iso file> autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=<cloud init yaml file root url>` I wonder is there a way to let the installer check the signature/hash of the iso file and the user-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The ISO file

It looks like *casper* does use the `md5sum.txt` file within the iso to confirm the contents are correct.  The output of this check is written to `/run/casper-md5check.json`.  This check is done after the iso has been mounted to `/cdrom`.  If you want to check the iso itself then you would need to write a custom check within the initramfs root.  I don't believe the iso is accessible in the installer environment because it has been deleted.  This is what the `mount` command shows in the installer environment after the initramfs root has been deleted.

```
/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso (deleted) on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
```

### The user-data file

I do not see anything built-in to *cloud-init* to verify a seed file.  I believe this is something you would have to code yourself.  It does look like the `user-data` file gets downloaded in the installer environment to `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt`.

There are a number of ways you could add a checksum validation.  The approach would depend if you just want to guarantee file integrity or if you want to guarantee security.

Comment: thanks I would like to guarantee security thus a gpg verification would be nice. If you can extend your answer about this I shall high appreciate your effort.